# MediaController appear on demand only

Tags: android, visibility, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have a video player in my android app. By default, the `MediaController` becomes visible upon playing for 3 seconds, if no activity.

The app goes through a series of short clips and that is fine, however, the MediaController pops up every time the video changes.

**Is it possible to have it only show on demand (tapping the video view)?**

I tried calling `controller.hide()` and `controller.show(0)` after I call `vidPlayer.start()`, but neither have worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I found my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679959/android-hiding-media-controller-functions. I had to change a few things, but the solution there works for the most part

Answer (score 0):

final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

```
    vView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)
    {
        @Override
        public void hide()
        {
            mc.show();
        }

        }); 
    vView.setMediaController(mc);

    vView.start();
```